# Remove end of each number in a vector in R

Tags: regex, r, indexing

I have a vector like this:

```
a <- c(11223344,55667788)
```

I would like to create a new vector cutting of the last two numbers of each entry in a:

```
[1] 112233 556677
```

Do I have to use regex to achieve this or is there a simple indexing trick that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're integers:

```
> trunc(a / 100)
[1] 112233 556677
```

Only if they're strictly positive, you could use floor:

```
> floor(a / 100)
[1] 112233 556677
```

Comment: I think the second is better (in case of negative numbers the first solution doesn't work)

Comment: Good point, switched the recommendation order and caveated `floor`.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use `sub`

```
 as.numeric(sub('..$','', a))
 #[1] 112233 556677
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substr` (or `substring`), cutting the number of characters off at two before the end

```
a <- c(11223344, 55667788)
substr(a, 1, nchar(a)-2)
# [1] "112233" "556677"
```

wrapping in `as.numeric` if necessary.